# How to produce different random results with DEAP?

Tags: python, algorithm, random, genetic-algorithm

I am using the DEAP library to maximize a metric, and I noticed that whenever I restart the algorithm (which is supposed to create a random list of binary values - 1s and 0s) it is producing the same initial values.

I became suspicious and copied their [basic DEAP example here](https://code.google.com/p/deap/) and re-ran the algorithms again:

```
import array, random
from deap import creator, base, tools, algorithms

creator.create("FitnessMax", base.Fitness, weights=(1.0,))
creator.create("Individual", array.array, typecode='b', fitness=creator.FitnessMax)

toolbox = base.Toolbox()

toolbox.register("attr_bool", random.randint, 0, 1)
toolbox.register("individual", tools.initRepeat, creator.Individual, toolbox.attr_bool, 10)
toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)

def evalOneMax(individual):
    return sum(individual),

toolbox.register("evaluate", evalOneMax)
toolbox.register("mate", tools.cxTwoPoints)
toolbox.register("mutate", tools.mutFlipBit, indpb=0.05)
toolbox.register("select", tools.selTournament, tournsize=3)

population = toolbox.population(n=10)

NGEN=40
for gen in range(NGEN):
    offspring = algorithms.varAnd(population, toolbox, cxpb=0.5, mutpb=0.1)
    fits = toolbox.map(toolbox.evaluate, offspring)
    for fit, ind in zip(fits, offspring):
        ind.fitness.values = fit
    population = offspring
```

The code above is exactly their example, but with the population and individual size reduced to 10. I ran the algorithm 5 times and it produced exact copies of each other. I also added a print statement to get the below output:

```
>python testGA.py
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
Starting the Evolution Algorithm...
Evaluating Individual: [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
Evaluating Individual: [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
Evaluating Individual: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
Evaluating Individual: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Evaluating Individual: [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
Evaluating Individual: [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
Evaluating Individual: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
Evaluating Individual: [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
Evaluating Individual: [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
Evaluating Individual: [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

This output is generated every time I call the function - In that order. They are exactly identical.

I have read that I shouldn't have to seed the random.randint function, and I tested it by writing a basic script that just prints out a list of 10 random ints ranged 0 to 1. This workd fine, it just seems to produce the same values when I feed it through DEAP.

Is this normal? How can I ensure that, when I run the algorithm, I get different 'individuals' every time?

**EDIT:**

Sorry for the late reply, here is the full source I am using:

```
import random, sys
from deap import creator, base, tools

class Max():

    def __init__(self):
        creator.create("FitnessMax", base.Fitness, weights=(1.0,))
        creator.create("Individual", list, fitness=creator.FitnessMax)

        INDIVIDUAL_SIZE = 10

        self.toolbox = base.Toolbox()
        self.toolbox.register("attr_bool", random.randint, 0, 1)
        self.toolbox.register("individual", tools.initRepeat, creator.Individual, self.toolbox.attr_bool, n=INDIVIDUAL_SIZE)
        self.toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, self.toolbox.individual)

        self.toolbox.register("mate", tools.cxTwoPoints)
        self.toolbox.register("mutate", tools.mutFlipBit, indpb=0.05)
        self.toolbox.register("select", tools.selTournament, tournsize=3)
        self.toolbox.register("evaluate", self.evaluate)

        print self.main()


    def evaluate(self, individual):
        # Some debug code
        print 'Evaluating Individual: ' + str(individual)
        return sum(individual),

    def main(self):

        CXPB, MUTPB, NGEN = 0.5, 0.2, 40
        random.seed(64)
        pop = self.toolbox.population(n=10)

        print "Starting the Evolution Algorithm..."

        fitnesses = list(map(self.toolbox.evaluate, pop))
        for ind, fit in zip(pop, fitnesses):
            ind.fitness.values = fit

        # ----------------------------------------------------------
        # Killing the program here - just want to see the population created
        sys.exit()

        print "Evaluated %i individuals" % (len(pop))

        for g in range(NGEN):
            print "-- Generation %i --" % (g)

            # Select the next genereation individuals
            offspring = self.toolbox.select(pop, len(pop))

            # Clone the selected individuals
            offspring = list(map(self.toolbox.clone, offspring))

            # Apply crossover and mutation on the offspring
            for child1, child2 in zip(offspring[::2], offspring[1::2]):
                if random.random() < CXPB:
                    self.toolbox.mate(child1, child2)
                    del child1.fitness.values
                    del child2.fitness.values

            for mutant in offspring:
                if random.random() < MUTPB:
                    self.toolbox.mutate(mutant)
                    del mutant.fitness.values

            # Evaluate the individuals with an invalid fitness
            invalid_ind = [ind for ind in offspring if not ind.fitness.valid]
            fitnesses = map(self.toolbox.evaluate, invalid_ind)
            for ind, fit in zip(invalid_ind, fitnesses):
                ind.fitness.values = fit

            print "\tEvaluated %i individuals" % (len(pop))

            pop[:] = offspring

            fits = [ind.fitness.values[0] for ind in pop]

            length = len(pop)
            mean = sum(fits) / length
            sum2 = sum(x*x for x in fits)
            std = abs(sum2 / length - mean**2)**0.5

            print "\tMin %s" % (min(fits))
            print "\tMax %s" % (max(fits))
            print "\tAvg %s" % (mean)
            print "\tStd %s" % (std)

class R_Test:
    def __init__(self):

        print str([random.randint(0, 1) for i in range(10)])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #rt = R_Test()
    mx = Max()
```

The R_Test class is there to test the random generation in Python. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423288/seed-and-random-numbers-in-python) that the seed is dynamically called if not given in Python, and I wanted to test this.

How I have been executing the above code has been as such:

```
> python testGA.py
... the 10 outputs
> python testGA.py
... the exact same outputs
> python testGA.py
... the exact same outputs
> python testGA.py
... the exact same outputs
> python testGA.py
... the exact same outputs
```

Obviously 5 times isn't exactly a strenuous test, but the fact that all 10 values are the same 5 times in a row raised a red flag.

Comment: There don't seem to be any references to `random.seed` in the source.

Comment: What happens if you explicitly call `random.seed()`? Do the values change at all?

Comment: I am one of DEAP lead developer. What you are observing is not normal, but I could not reproduce it using the code you provided. Could you put up the exact code that you used?

Comment: Can you try to just do the imports and print the first random integer? Try to single out the line that fix the seed. What version of DEAP and what OS are you using?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I have edited the question to include the actual source code I am using. @CmdNtrf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you specify a seed for the random number generator in your main function. Simply comment the line : `random.seed(64)` and you will get different results every time you execute your program.

In DEAP example files, a specific seed is set because we also use these examples as integration tests. If after a modification in the framework base code, the output of an example is different, we want to know. It also allow us to bench the time required by each example and provide a ballpark estimate to our users. The results of these benchmarks are available online at http://deap.gel.ulaval.ca/speed/.

Comment: This did it, I am sorry I didn't see this sooner. Thank-you.